# Запятая и тире в одном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Подскажите, какие тут должны быть знаки препинания?
Верно ли стоят тире и запятая?
**Если место регистрации организации — Санкт-Петербург, то необходимо...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно,т.к. союз "если..то.."- парный, перед "то" нужна запятая. Тире м-ду подлеж. и сказуемым, выраж-ми существит. в И.п.

Comment: Вир-озное об-ащение с сокр.! Пор-овала, Диана! К-уто.